# How to chose what to boot from in VMware

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

How can I boot from the cd in Vmware? I don't know how to chose what to boot from. Please help me I tried pressing F2 at startup and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure which VMWare product you are using. If you are using Workstation, you want to go to the menu: VM > Power > Power on to BIOS (I believe - I don't have it on my current computer). Graphically, select the VM client computer, click the drop-down arrow next to the "play" power on icon, and then select, boot to bios. Inside the bios you can select boot order.

Note, if you haven't already select the CD-ROM or ISO image to use, you first want to go into the VM settings, and change the cd-rom options to select the desire physical drive or image file (and be sure to check the boxes that attach the cd-rom during boot-up.

Here is a video that may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1yMW5vQbuk